# AngularJS how to convert string "yyyyMMdd" to date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

can you help please to convert below in Angularjs
I have  value "20141023" and would like to convert to date in AngularJS and then displayed View in format dd/MMM/yyyy
Many thanks 
N.

Comment: This is a javascript specific question, is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use regular expression please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  var st = "20130510";
  var pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
  $scope.date = new Date(st.replace(pattern, '$1-$2-$3'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    {{date | date :'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) (see the basic examples here) along with the [AngularJS wrapper](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).

Using MomentJS you can define your format easily.

```
moment().format('YYYYMMDD')
```

If you want to look more into it, please refer to their [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/).