# format a string like a date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-formatting

I'm receiving a "*date*" represented by a string in the form **yyyymmdd** from a database table over which I have no control. (I cannot modify the type/format of the date field)

I would like to insert the character '**/**' at the right place. (*20150113 = 2015/01/13*)

As I haven't been able to use `new Date('20150113')` I am using a regex to insert the slash like so:

```
string = string.toString().replace(/(^[0-9]{4})/g , "$1\/");
string = string.replace(/(^[0-9\/]{7})/g , "$1\/");
```

Is it possible to merge both regexes into one or is there an existing function (angular, javascript) that can understand that date format (*20150113*)?

Comment: You might find similar question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676184/angularjs-how-to-convert-string-yyyymmdd-to-date, MomentJS is another option.

Comment: If you sure about your format **yyyymmdd** then you can do without REGEX `String dateStr = "20150113";
   dateStr = dateStr.substring(0, 4) + "/" +  dateStr.substring(4, 6) + "/" + dateStr.substring(6);`

Comment: @MattMcCabe I searched everywhere for a similar question (as I always do) and I couldn't find that one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
string = string.toString().replace(/(^[0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/g , "$1\/$2\/$3");
```