# Angular JS date format to longdatestring

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to convert date from my angular code 
"/Date(1481843459627)/" to any understandable date format.

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676184/angularjs-how-to-convert-string-yyyymmdd-to-date) but i was successful only if input was a time stamp.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: dont you get date value for `Date(1481843459627)` ?

Comment: no. I tried angular built in filter |date too. no luck

Comment: convert the value into new Date(1481843459627) then try the angular date filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format date by creating a filter which will convert that date to your formatted output.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.filter('ctime', function($filter){
  return function(jsonDate){
    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    var filterDate = $filter('date')(date, "MMMM d, y"); 
    return filterDate ;
  };

});
app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.date = '/Date(1481843459627)/';
});
```

Then you can do in html like this

```
<p ng-bind="date | ctime"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
{{1481843459627 | date:'medium'}}
```

Easy and sleek.

In JavaScript you can simply use:

```
var dateNew = new Date(1481843459627);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use the format in view page or filter in the controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    {{date | date :'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Parse the date into the required date format. Because the mentioned value isn't the valid date format. So to convert the date first need to convert into the correct format. like as 1481843459627 and need to remove the remaining string.

```
var val ="/Date(1481843459627)/";
 var date = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple angular date filtes for this purpose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

        <p>Date = {{ today | date }}</p>
        <p>{{today | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('datCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.today = 1481843459627; //Your date parameter
        });
    </script>

    <p>The date filter formats a date object to a readable format.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Find more about angular date filters [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)